# get url, print it and go to the next - PHP

Tags: php

I have a script that gets all images from a website and put this urls into a textarea all together. When I send this form I receive this in a POST variable.

so:

```
$var = $_POST['textarea'];
```

this $var content is like this:

```
http://site1.com/image1.jpg
http://site2.com/image2.jpg
http://site3.com/image3.jpg
http://site4.com/image4.jpg
http://site5.com/image5.jpg
http://site6.com/image6.jpg
...
```

I need to get each url separately to print the image on the screen.
I want to print image1, image2...

```
<img src=http://site1.com/image1.jpg> <img src=http://site2.com/image2.jpg>
```

how can I do this?
thank you!

Comment: you need to [iterate](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) through the array.  Give it a try and if you get stuck come back for some help with your code.

Comment: can I foreach till \n or <br>?

Comment: `$var = explode("\n", $var);` to get the array (assuming the lines are really separated by a newline)

Comment: yes as @mgansler says above.  I didnt realise that `$var` was a string, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really quite basic:

```
// Convert a string of '\n' separated URLs into an array of img tags
$list = array_map(
    function ($url) { return '<img src="' . trim($url) . '">'; },
    explode("\n", $var)
);

// Output an array of img tags as a single space delimited string
echo implode(' ', $list);
```

You should have a look at what all of the following functions do:

- [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) - Split a string by string
- [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) - Applies the callback to the elements of the given arrays
- [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) - Join array elements with a string